# Core Data + web service - how to manage retina images

Tags: ios, web-services, core-data, uiimage, retina-display

Just using Core Data alone, I can read in a plist file and set the image for an object like this:

```
[itemObject setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:[item valueForKey:@"image"]] forKey:@"image"];
```

This code will automatically choose the retina (@2x) version of the file in the app bundle if the device has a retina display.

How can I handle this if I'm getting the image from a web service instead? I guess I have to upload both 1x and 2x images to the web service. So do I create two separate fields for the item, like image-lowRes and image-highRes, and do a device check before I request the image data?
I figure this is a common scenario so I'm hoping someone can give some advice from experience on the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pass the device density to your web service and potentially have three versions of your image assets, 1x, 1.5x, and 2x.  The 1.5x is with Android in mind.

Using the Android naming convention, you could store these in mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi folders, though these details are entirely up to you.